# Firestore API changes - how to decode objects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm still new to Firestore and trying to work out how to use it. I've noticed that in several SOF questions and some parts of the Firestore loco it appears that Firestore can return objects of a specific class rather than dictionaries of data.

For example, in the doco (Which appears to be partially updated) it says:

> The previous example used `getData()` to get the contents of the
>   document as a map, but it's often more convenient to use a custom
>   object type. In Add Data, you defined a City class that you used to
>   define each city. You can turn your document back into a City object
>   by calling `.getData(City.class)`.

However the code sample directly following it looks to be updated:

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let city = document.flatMap({ City(dictionary: $0.data()) }) {
        print("City: \(city)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

And is using an init to pass a dictionary.

Does anyone know if Firestore is going to include dictionary to object decoding? From what I can find out at the moment, it appears to be dropped or not available.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I don't understand you clearly, But if you want to find City Object Class in Swift it's here.

```
struct City {

    let name: String
    let state: String?
    let country: String?
    let capital: Bool?
    let population: Int64?

    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.name = name

        self.state = dictionary["state"] as? String
        self.country = dictionary["country"] as? String
        self.capital = dictionary["capital"] as? Bool
        self.population = dictionary["population"] as? Int64
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I was asking was if Firestore has a builtin ability to do the data to object mapping as per the documentation. Or do we have to do it ourselves as per the sample code.